# How can I add a regression plot for a multiple regression for certain x values?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, linear-regression

I am trying to create a regression plot for a multiple regression equation at the points that carb= 20, 30, 40 and 50. My end product will be a graph that has four plots. I don't know what I am doing wrong here. Could anyone help?

This is my regression model:

```
lm1 = lm(data = diet, Calories~ carb + fat+ carb*fat)
```

Here I am trying to create models for `carb = 20, 30, 40, 50` values:

```
pred = data.frame(cal_pred = predict(lm1, diet), carb= c(20,30,40,50))

ggplot(data = diet, aes(x = Calories, y = fat)) +
  geom_point(color = 'blue') +
  geom_line(color = 'red', data = pred, aes(x=cal_pred, y=carb))


dput(diet)
```

> structure(list(Calories = c(202.149, 275.272, 294.67, 451.524, 
>   261.315, 365.13, 296.69, 353.464, 383.429, 420.748, 296.021), 
>       carb = c(20L, 25L, 30L, 20L, 30L, 20L, 35L, 50L, 40L, 24L, 
>       32L), fat = c(8L, 12L, 13L, 40L, 12L, 30L, 10L, 15L, 32L, 
>       45L, 20L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))

Comment: Can you include the output of `dput(diet)` in your question?

Comment: Thank you, I added dput(diet) now.